# Switch between dark mode and light mode to GTK don`t work in xorg server

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, gtk

I'm trying to switch between dark mode and light mode to the `gtk` applications on my computer, in real time, from the terminal.

I use the `arch linux`, on `xorg server` (`X11`) without graphical environment (I use `dwm` window manager), so the direct `gnome` or `plasma` configurations don't apply to me.

Looking for information, the most accurate one I've found is this page from the arch wiki: [Dark_mode_switching](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Dark_mode_switching).

According to the requirements, I understand that I should use `xsettings`, but the theme does not change:

```
$ xfconf-query -c xsettings -p /Net/ThemeName
Adwaita
```

```
$ xfconf-query -c xsettings -p /Net/ThemeName -s "Adwaita-dark"
```

Where am I going wrong? Is there any better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GTK#Dark_theme_variant):

- If using GTK3: Edit `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` and append

  ```
  gtk-application-prefer-dark-theme = 1
  ```
- Or if using GTK4: Run

  ```
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface color-scheme prefer-dark
  ```

  in your terminal.